# How to extract all dynamic table data from a website using selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to web scraping. I am trying to extract table data from the Forbes Top Multinational Performers list. I was able to successfully extract some data. However, I only was able to get the top 10 from the list. The table contains ads in between. How can I get all the data?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd


driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:/Users/Shirly.Ang3/Desktop/BUSINESS STAT/GGR/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')


url = "https://www.forbes.com/top-multinational-performers/list/"


driver.get(url)

wait_row = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
rows = wait_row.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,
                                        './/*[@id="the_list"]/tbody[@id="list-table-body"]')))


data = []

for row in rows:
    for i in row.find_elements_by_class_name("data"):
        try:
            if i.is_displayed(): 

                row_dict = {}

                row_dict['Rank'] = i.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[2]').text
                row_dict['Link'] = i.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[3]/a[@href]').get_attribute("href")
                row_dict['Company'] = i.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[3]').text
                row_dict['Industry'] = i.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[4]').text
                row_dict['Country'] = i.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[5]').text

                data.append(row_dict)

        except: 
            continue        

driver.close()             

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_csv("Forbes_TEST.csv", sep=",", index=False)
```

Comment: well that is called web scraping. Identify the objects in the DOM three. Go to the website and in the developer console select the elements that you want (or don't want such as ads) and begin writing your code. You can filter by class/id or type of the element.

Answer (score 0):

To get all 250 records you  just need to add code to scroll to the bottom of the page to your existing code. So add:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(5)
```

before:

```
data = []
```

and add `import time`

But saying that your code is really slow. Even with setting your `wait_row` to 3 it took 1m5.933s to run on my machine. The following code took 0m12.978s to run.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:/Users/Shirly.Ang3/Desktop/BUSINESS STAT/GGR/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://www.forbes.com/top-multinational-performers/list/"
driver.get(url)
wait_row = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
rows = wait_row.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, './/*[@id="the_list"]/tbody[@id="list-table-body"]')))
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(5)
ranks = []
links = []
companies = []
industries = []
countries = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table", {"id": "the_list"})
for tr in table.find_all("tr", {"class": "data"}):
    tds = tr.find_all("td")
    ranks.append(tds[1].text)
    links.append(tds[2].find('a')['href'])
    companies.append(tds[2].text)
    industries.append(tds[3].text)
    countries.append(tds[4].text)
data = zip(ranks, links, companies, industries, countries)
with open('Forbes_TEST_02.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csv_out = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csv_out.writerow(['Rank', 'Link', 'Company','Industry', 'Country'])
    csv_out.writerows(data)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Really appreciate it!